# Conversion and overload deduction based on return type

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, return-type, auto

I've seen in the C++ core guidelines that it is preferable to return output values from functions.

I am trying to understand if this is convenient for generic code.

For instance, in order to convert from a string to a certain value I'd normally do something like:

```
template<class T>
T convertTo(const std::string& value)
  {
  // Do conversion
  return convertedValue;
  }

// Usage
convertTo<float>("test");
```

Without specifying the type I'd do:

```
template<class T>
void convertTo(const std::string& value, T& outputValue)
  {
  // Do conversion
  // outputValue = convertedType
  }

// Usage
float myVar{};
convertTo("test", myVar);
```

I know also that you can do something like:

```
auto convertTo(const std::string& value, anotherInputPerhaps) ->decltype(myexpression)
  {
  // get the type to return basing on anotherInputPerhaps
  return /*convertedValue*/
  }
```

The problem here is how to get the right converted value, possibly without passing any input or maybe using a defaulted value. Is this possible?

Thanks

[EDIT] Looking for something that does not introduce overhead

Comment: "The problem here is how to get the right converted value, possibly without passing any input" Are you asking if the compiler can read your mind?

Comment: @George I think he want to return the value, not get it as by reference argument.

Comment: @SHR read my mind, yes

Comment: `anotherInputPerhaps` you suggest need to specify the input or the tag, which means it is exactly what SHR wrote below

Comment: Start by figurinng out what **real code** you want to write in place of `// Do conversion`.

Comment: @Moia my question was not clear enough, that's true. However the "perhaps" was meant to indicate that a parameter may be perhaps needed if there is no other way to execute this operation. I also wrote: "possibly without passing any input or maybe using a defaulted value", so that the function signature might have another parameter, but by means of some magic there was no need to specify it

Comment: @n.m. it was just to express a concept,so didn't thought so relevant

Comment: @svoltron a template need to be deducted at compile-time. So you need to provide some "tip" to deduce the correct type.

Comment: yes I was just wondering if maybe there was another way to deduce it. The Jarod reply for example seems that can achieve that

Comment: A concept of what? Of converting a string to an unknown arbitrary type T? It isn't at all clear how this concept can possibly work. What `convertTo<MyCustomClass>` will do?

Comment: the point is that I'm not really interested in the conversion per se, I'm interested in the C++ mechanics.. this exact problem is applicable to many other contexts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With default value you can also do:

```
template<class T>
T convertTo(const std::string& value, T default_value)
{
   // DO Conversion
   if( conversion success)
     return convertedValue;
   else 
     return default_value;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
float myVar= DEFAULT_VALUE;
myVar = convertTo("test", myVar);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but nope, this unfortunately is not because I wanted to avoid to pass an extra argument or to specify the template parameter. However it seems there is no other solution..

Answer (score 3):

You might return class with conversion operator, something like:

```
struct Converter
{
    template <typename T>
    operator T() const /*&&*/ { /*Do conversion*/ return {}; }

    const std::string& s;
};

Converter convert(const std::string& value)
{
  return { value };
}
```

With usage:

```
float f = convert("test");
int i = convert("test");
std::vector<int> v = convert("test");
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/153bb6bb43433f13)

Comment: This sounds good. I read about something similar in another question here on SO. How about overhead?

Comment: Also problems with explicit constructors I think

Comment: This idea [doesn't quite work](https://ideone.com/D5a9sJ). Try converting to any class type with more than one overloaded ctor/assignment.

Comment: @n.m.: Indeed, with ambiguous overloads, we can no longer be implicit.

Comment: @svoltron: For overhead, you have to check with your compiler, but it seems straightforward to inline the call to have just the conversion as your `convertTo<MyType>(s)`.

Comment: yep, I'm gonna check that. The only drawback is then just the possible problem with explicit constructors. Anyway really good answer